# Pass parameter to nested procedure or create temp table and check if table exists

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following structure of stored procedures:

```
exec A -> exec B -> exec C -> exec D
```

where stored procedure A calls stored procedure B, B calls C and C calls D.

I need a special behavior to happen in stored procedure D based on a condition that is determined in stored procedure A. Of course one option is to pass param from A to B, then from B to C, then from C to D, but I was wondering if I can simply just create a temp table prior to executing A, then when I am in stored procedure D I can just check if temp table exists and perform my logic based on that.Finally in the line right after exec A, I will drop the temp table

EDIT: I am aware that if proc D is called from a different procedure the condition will be treated as not exists. Also I am aware of temp table name can clash with another temp table with the same name. Other than that...

Is there any unwanted side effects to doing the later solution?

Answer (score 1):

The temp tables or (#tables) should have the lifespan of the session. In the case you describe you should be able to create the #table in PROC A and reference it on PROC D without any special considerations.

Please note that if you take this approach you are creating a direct dependency between PROC D and PROC A, since now you have to call PROC A to create the Temp table you are using on PROC D. If you are OK with this then go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a persistent [Params] table. I have procedure:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE SetParam @name VarChar(20), @value VarChar(50) AS BEGIN
    -- I don't like MERGE, but it could be used here as well.
    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO [Params] ([Name], [Value]) 
        VALUES (@name, @value)
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        UPDATE [Params] SET [Value] = @Value
        WHERE [Name] = @name
    END CATCH
END
GO
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE GetParam @name VarChar(20), @value VarChar(50) OutPut AS BEGIN
    SET @value = NULL
    -- Try - Catch could be here as well
    SELECT @value FROM [Params] WHERE [Name]=@name
END
GO

-- In A
EXEC SetParam 'Param','Value'

-- In D
DECLARE @ParamValue Int
EXEC GetParam 'ParamName', @ParamValue OutPut
```